# How to determine the age of a GitHub personal access token?

Tags: github, hashicorp-vault

IAM looking into using GitHub personal access tokens as a way to login to a Hashicorp Vault instance for my company.

Is their any way to audit the age of personal access tokens used by members of our GitHub team?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max_ttl, default_ttl, and number of times the token can be renewed. I believe you do this when you are configuring the endpoint where Github will talk to Vault.

```
$ vault write auth/github/config organization=The Cloud Inc \
 token_ttl="30h" \ 
 token_max_ttl="100h"
 token_policy="readonly"
....
```

I also found some reference links from Hashicorp:

- https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/github/index.html
- https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/github.html